# how to perform solr joins

Tags: java, solr

Hi i am trying to join two documents from two collections in solr

### Solr document-1  Collection-A

```
{
    "student_id": "123",
    "name": "rahul",
    "adrress": "addr001"
}
```

### solr document-2 Collection-B

```
{
    "address_id": "addr001",
    "street_name": "XYZ street",
    "colony": "ABC colony"
}
```

### I am expecting my final document should be like below after join

```
{
    "student_id": "123",
    "name": "rahul",
    "street_name": "XYZ street",
    "colony": "ABC colony"
}
```

Can anyone help me how to perform joins in solr with relevant example as per my requirements ?

Comment: Both document in same collection ?

Comment: yes both documents are from same collection. Can you explain if documents are from different collection also? @AshrafulIslam

Comment: Join based on what ?? student_id ?

Comment: join based on address_id.....@AshrafulIslam